# How to create rainmeter style widgets for a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, widget

This is probably a trivial question, but I feel like it would be useful toward web design. I really like the style of some of the Rainmeter widgets and I wanted to know if there was any way to maybe incorporate them into a website. To be honest, I don't really care for its practical purposes, otherwise I would have gone with the usual widgets you can find on the web which were developed for websites. I am more worried about its aesthetics, and frankly... The widgets I've seen for the web are not the easiest on the eyes (Maybe you know a place where there are some beautiful widgets). Perhaps this is no longer even a widget in a sense, but just an image. An animated image. Surely there is a way though to incorporate the resources you find for Rainmeter onto a website. I tried to answer it myself, and so far only came up with this: create the image on a photo editing program, and then animate it on the website (could be tricky). Perhaps there is a way to edit a widget's style? So my question is really, how would you create/incorporate the widgets you find in the Rainmeter libraries? For example, to recreate what you see on the link below. (With animation).

http://customize.org/rainmeter/skins/67189

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably searching for the wrong keywords. You should be looking for charts and/ or gauges and maybe graphs. The most examples/ libraries will be found including the keyword "javascript" or "css" and now "html5"

This will probably never have a concrete answer, as it seems new browsers introduce new inconsistencies in the way the process or integrate html standards. I've noticed this especially with JavaScript animation. The browsers that support them tend to be more consistent in the way they display CSS transformations. I, personally, haven't delved too much into HTML5 canvas, but that will most likely be the way to go in the near future.

Alternatively, search for dashboard themes.